# "sample must be less than `1`" error in tensorflow distributions

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm currently using the beta distribution class from tensorflow and have the following problem:

Snippet of my code:

```
self.dist = tf.distributions.Beta(concentration1=alpha, concentration0=beta, validate_args=True, allow_nan_stats=False)
...
def neglogp(self, x):
    clipped_x = tf.clip_by_value(x, 0.0000000001, 0.9999999999)
    return tf.reduce_sum(-self.dist.log_prob(clipped_x), axis=-1)
```

Error:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: assertion failed: [sample must be less than `1`.] [Condition x < y did not hold element-wise:] [x (output/clip_by_value_1:0) = ] [[0.900631309 0.142189667 0.749241889...]...] [y (model/Beta/log_prob/ones:0) = ] [1]
     [[node model/Beta/log_prob/assert_less/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert (defined at src/BetaDistribution.py:55) ]]
```

So I thought I can just use the clip_by_value function to make sure every value in x is below 1, but I still get the same error. I'm no tensorflow expert by any means so does maybe anyone know why I still get this error and why the clipping apparently doesn't work. Or the mistakes lies somewhere else I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake:

0.9999999999 was too precise for the float32 tensor, so it rounded it to 1 and the clipping used 1 as max value.

```
>>> x = tf.Variable([0.9999999])
>>> x.numpy()
array([0.9999999], dtype=float32)
>>> x = tf.Variable([0.99999999])
>>> x.numpy()
array([1.], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Ok, but what's your solution?

Comment: I used clipped_x = tf.clip_by_value(x, 0.0000001, 0.9999999). So only seven digits after the 0., now it fits the float32 tensor and doesn't get rounded up to 1.